# A good example of PermissionOverwrite in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to use this feature but can't get the hang of it. Here's something I've tried.

```py
# lockdown
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def lockdown(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    await ctx.send("This channel has been locked. You will need to change the settings to revert this action.")

    if ctx.guild.default_role not in channel.overwrites:
        overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermmisionOverwrite(send_messages=False)
        }
        await channel.edit(overwrites=overwrites)
```

It doesn't seem to work though, and I know why. I don't know how to use this function properly. Seeing the API documentation made me even confused. Can I like, get a good example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Where you put discord.PermmisionOverwrite, you misspelt. You can put discord.PermissionOverwrite instead

Comment: Welcome to SO! perhaps this answer is more suited for comments.